# Default namespace in XML file doesn't work with XSD, why?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

I have a XML file and XSD for it. In this form it works fine:

```
<tns:Users xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema">
    <User>
        <FirstName>Max</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gordon</LastName>
        <Salary>80000</Salary>
    </User>
    <User>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <LastName>Disel</LastName>
        <Salary>75000</Salary>
    </User>
</tns:Users>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" 
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema">
  <element name="Users">
    <complexType>
      <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
        <element name="User">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="FirstName" type="string"/>
              <element name="LastName" type="string"/>
              <element name="Salary" type="int"/>
            </sequence>
          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

I wonder why it doesn't in another: if I omitted tns prefixes in xml file? I mean it would became a default namespace then:

```
<Users xmlns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema">
    <User>
        <FirstName>Max</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gordon</LastName>
        <Salary>80000</Salary>
    </User>
    <User>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <LastName>Disel</LastName>
        <Salary>75000</Salary>
    </User>
</Users>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because these are different XML documents.

In the first XML:

```
<tns:Users xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema">
    <User>
        <FirstName>Max</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gordon</LastName>
        <Salary>80000</Salary>
    </User>
    <User>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <LastName>Disel</LastName>
        <Salary>75000</Salary>
    </User>
</tns:Users>
```

only the root element `Users` is in `http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema` namespace.
All other elements are in {no namespace}.

This corresponds to your XML schema. It does define the target namespace.
But it applies only to global element `Users`.
All other elements are declared locally, and their namespace is determined
by the `elementFormDefault` attribute of the `<schema ...>` element.
You don't specify this attribute, but it exists and its default value is "unqualified".
That means that all local elements have no namespace.

Now, let's look in your second XML:

```
<Users xmlns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema">
    <User>
        <FirstName>Max</FirstName>
        <LastName>Gordon</LastName>
        <Salary>80000</Salary>
    </User>
    <User>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <LastName>Disel</LastName>
        <Salary>75000</Salary>
   </User>
</Users>
```

Here, you bluntly specify that **all** elements are in `http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema` namespace (both the root and everything else). But this doesn't comply with your XML schema!

Comment: "But this doesn't comply with your XML schema!" Why? I pointed out targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" so my XSD is targeted for the exact namespace where my xml file is.

Comment: Because XML works with full names. What you see in XML document are local names. But the full XML name is this: {namespaceURI}localName.
So, in the first XML, you have, for instance: {}FirstName.
But in the second XML, the same will be: {http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema}FirstName.
Got the difference? If not, please read some basic XML book. I recommend this: O'REILLY, "XML IN A NUTSHELL". targetNamespace in <schema> applies only to global components (basically those whose root is <schema>). Whether it applies to the locally declared elements is controlled by elementFormDefault attribute